# SQL Server Management Studio  error "Saved settings file cannot be found"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is my problem:
Every time I start the "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio", I get a warning

```
The automatically saved settings file "\\Settings\CurrentSettings-2012-02-13.vssettings' cannot be found.
```

The message goes on to say :

```
"You can change this file on the 'Import and Export Settings' Tools Options page". The IDE will use your most recent settings for this session.
```

Where is this setting? How to fix this?

thanks!

Comment: How did you finally fix it?

Answer (score 8):

you can try with theses steps :

> In the `Tools menu`, `select Options.`
>
> Select `Environment folder`, `choose Import and Export Settings`
>
> In Automatically save my settings to this file, enter the location you will backup.
>
> Select OK.

This file is in : `%userprofile%\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings`

Nota : if you don't find file, you can get another file from your coleague

Comment: This works, you don't have to directly play with Registry. 
Assuming the file doesn't exist, create an empty notepad file, call it something like "settings.vssettings", select it and click Save. No need to bother your colleagues :)

Comment: There is no 'Environment folder' in tools->options in my copy of SSMS.

Answer (score 7):

1. If  SQL Server Management Studio is open close it
2. Open Registry Editor Navigate to the location
   _HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL
   Server\100\Tools\Shell_
3. Edit the value of the Reg Key "VisualStudioLocation" to

   `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio`

Close Registry Editor and check if the problem is fixed

Comment: Do not have that location.  I see `_HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Client`    (under client is ExceptionMessageBox)  there is also a `130` folder with nothing under it.

Answer (score 4):

In my case: we have Documents folder as mapped network drive and it seems SQL management studio has issues with that. As a quick workaround I created settings file outside this network drive and it works. Only downside is settings are not synchronized but honestly I don't care :)

Answer (score 0):

Use your favorite registry editor, or use regedt32.exe if you don't have a decent one.  Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<vsver>\profile`, where `<vsver>` is the numeric version of visual studio that you are using, e.g. 6.0, 7.1, 8.0, 9.0.  In there, you will find an entry `AutoSaveFile`.  Edit this entry to point to a vssettings file that you want as your default settings file.  If you don't have such a file, create one via "Tools->Import and Export Settings...->Export selected environments settings" first.  Typical value for `AutoSaveFile` is `%vsspv_visualstudio_dir%\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings`, and typical value for `DefaultSettingsDirectory` is `%vsspv_visualstudio_dir%\Settings\`.

The statement in the error message "You can change this file on the 'Import and Export Settings' Tools Options page" seems to be incorrect.  In particular, I was unable to reset the defaults no matter how many different ways I saved or loaded settings using the 'Import and Export Settings' Tools Options page.  I had to resort to modifying the registry.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Turns out I had renamed the drive and this was causing the problem. Renaming it back to the original (as seen in the path in the error message) fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it with no registry changes.
Based on the instructions from this site:
http://sebastian.expert/the-automatically-saved-settings-file-currentsettings-vssettings-cannot-be-found/

Basically you need to change the default path in options.
Go to Tools/Options then Environment/Import and Export Settings
Change the path to existing one.

Comment: You should paraphrase what the link says. See [`How to reference material written by others`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Answer (score 0):

I found a lot of solutions which suggested to edit the following registry: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\VisualStudioLocation

If there are people(like me) who do not have that entry, I managed to fix it by editing this one:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\Profile\AutoSaveFile

I run MS SQL Server 2008 R2