# SQL Server Management Studio error “Saved settings file cannot be found” Virtual Machine Win 8.1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, ssms

Every time I start the "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio", I get the following warning

[image]

but the issue doesn't end up here.

I have searched a lot on stack and done a lot of Googling as well. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747693/sql-server-management-studio-error-saved-settings-file-cannot-be-found), but the strange thing is that there is no such location as `_HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell_`

[image]

Note: I have already installed SQL Server successfully. Once I installed SQL Server I installed Management Studio.

I have searched a lot but couldn't find a better solution. I found a [video](http://we.tl/XrGoutMqBq) of the issue I am facing.

Comment: Did you try uninstalling then reinstalling SSMS?

Comment: What version of SSMS are you running? (See Help > About.) Also, is this on a virtual machine? Are you using a roaming Windows profile? Did you try doing what the error message says and specified a different location for your settings file?

Comment: I am running it on virtual machine.

Comment: Actually I am new to .net and working on windows after a long time using Mac from a long ago.

Comment: 11.0.2100.60 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue.

- I have uninstalled .net framework.
- Re-Install the latest .net framework, with the latest service pack.

Now its working fine for me. Hope will help someone other in future.

Note: I didn't changed anything in registry editor.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Management Studio is failing to find the required settings file, so the work around may be to reset the settings and save them to get rid of the warning.

If you go in to the menu options:

<kbd>Tools > Import and Export Settings...</kbd>

Then **Reset all settings**

[image]

You will then be given an option on the next tab to save your current settings if you have any. Be sure to select a valid location. Then if you have any custom settings, re-apply them and export them again to a saved file as backup. Finally, save the new configuration on the VM otherwise next time you spin it up, the issue will re-occur.

Comment: but how can I goto tools it doesn't allowing me to open management studios, and In installation wizard there is no such option in tools.

Comment: @Saad The warning message you showed in your question is not preventing you from opening Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved mine as added write permissions for **Users** to the file *CurrentSettings.vssettings* (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Visual Studio 2013\settings)

[image]